# react syntax isn't recognized

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am new to react, I am trying to run a simple code example I found, the perpuse of the code is to show a few tabs. I am running into some technical problems.

I am getting this error: " Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined " on the first line of my JS code: import React from 'react';

it seems like it doesnt recognize my react code.

please help,
Thank you very much :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard Support Tool Center</title>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/babel" src="/dashboards/react/dashboardCenter.js"></script>
</html>
```

React/JS:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Tabs from './Tabs';
require('/dashboards/css/tabStyles.css');

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>Tabs Demo</h1>
        <Tabs>
            <div label="Gator">
                See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
            </div>
            <div label="Croc">
                After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
            </div>
            <div label="Sarcosuchus">
                Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
            </div>
        </Tabs>
    </div>
);
}

const container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
render(<App />, container);
```

Comment: Try removing the `type` attribute from the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a reference to requrejs library in your html:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" ></script>
```

**Edit**

`import` and `require` in your js file are not recognizable by most browsers. You have to use a [ES6 module system](https://flaviocopes.com/es-modules/). You have a long road ahead ;)

Comment: it doesnt show the previous error,
now its just throwing exception on the first line, any idea's ?  Uncaught Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: You have to transpile your javascript code to make the browser understand it. `import` and `require` keywords are not standard javascript and most browsers don't understand them. Google for `transpile Javascript` and `Javascript Module System`